# How to use AWS_MSK_IAM sasl mechanism with a kafka producer jar?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-iam, aws-msk

I have a fat jar called producer which produces messages.I want to use it to produce messages to a MSK serverless cluster. The jar takes the following arguments-

```
-topic --num-records  --record-size  --throughput --producer.config /configLocation/
```

As my MSK serverless cluster uses IAM based authentication, i have provided the following settings in my **producer.config**-

```
bootstrap.servers=boot-url
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
```

The way this jar usually works is by providing a username and password with the **sasl.jaas.config** property.

However, with MSK serverless we have to use the IAM role attached to our EC2 instance.

When my executing the current jar  by using

```
java - jar producer.jar -topic --num-records  --record-size  --throughput --producer.config /configLocation/
```

I get the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler for configuration sasl.client.callback.handler.class: Class software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler could not be found.
```

I don't understand how to make the producer jar find the class present in the external jar **aws-msk-iam-auth-1.1.1-all.jar**.

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to create your jar? Is it an uber jar? Did you add the IAM library as a dependency?

Comment: The fat/uber jar is a blackbox but I'm pretty sure they wouldn't have a dependency on anything aws related as they are availing the services of a different cloud provider.

Comment: You can use `jar -tf` to examine that "black box", but as the error says, that class is not available on the classpath... You can `export CLASSPATH` or use `-cp` flag of `java` command to otherwise include external JARs in your runtime execution.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Cricketeer. I examined the jar and confirmed the dependency isn't present . I'm gonna be using the explicitly specified classpath in the meantime.

Comment: If that works for you, feel free to provide the full command in an answer below

Comment: I didn't get the chance to try manually setting the classpath as we were able to request the jar to be updated with required AWS IAM dependencies. TPTB didn't want to modify the cp for this singular jar when the option of inclusion was available.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have answered the question based on my findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it isn't possible to override the classpath specified in MANIFEST.MF in case of a jar by using commandline options like --cp. What worked in my case was to have the jar's pom include the missing dependency.

> When you use the -jar command-line option to run your program as an
> executable JAR, then the Java CLASSPATH environment variable will be
> ignored, and also the -cp and -classpath switches will be ignored and,
> In this case, you can set your java classpath in the
> META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file by using the Class-Path attribute.

https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html

Comment: I feel like that's an old (non-official) blog and that I've definitely added external JARs when running others.